# Python: Is there a way to save random numbers in the list as sorted?

Tags: python, sorting, random

I have a code that stores 9 random numbers in the list.

now, I want to sort the values in the list object.

I found two method. but these methods have some problems.

This is my code 1:

```
import random

array = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    array.append(random.randrange(i, 100))

array.sort()
print(array)
```

output:

```
[14, 23, 31, 33, 50, 65, 86, 96, 99]
```

This code works well, but must be executed after the 'for loop'. I want to execute sort in the 'for loop'.

This is my code 2:

```
import random

array = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    array.append(random.randrange(i, 100))
    array.sort()

print(array)
```

output:

```
[8, 22, 23, 26, 39, 48, 51, 53, 71]
```

This code works well, but you will run the sort nine times.

Is there any good way?

Comment: "I want to execute sort in the 'for loop'." - why? Is there something else happening in the loop that needs to work with the sorted list, or is this just a preference?

Comment: but must be executed after the 'for loop' << so, why not?

Comment: `sorted([random.randrange(i, 100) for i in range(9)])`

Comment: You could use the standard `bisect` module to find the proper place to insert your random number into the list, such that it always remains in sorted order.  But doing this once per iteration of the loop would likely take more time in total than doing a single `.sort()` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will add if statement in for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I really understand your meaning, you want to get an sorted array during the loop for each iterative time, that is to say, you want to do something **insert into sorted array**. `bisect` can help here.

Following code will ensure array are always sorted in the loop, but not sort each time, it binary search and insert the new element into the array:

```py
import random
import bisect
array = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    bisect.insort(array, random.randrange(i, 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would it matter to execute the sort after the `for`-loop?
The number of comparisons is basically the same.
It is actually better to sort it afterward to avoid unnecessary comparisons.

In case you want a two-liner on how to do this with list comprehension:

```py
array = [random.randrange(i, 100) for i in range(10)]
array.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print (sorted([random.randrange(i, 100) for i in range(10)]))
```

Output:

```
[8, 26, 48, 62, 68, 77, 78, 83, 94, 96]
```

Comment: This of course also works just fine. I usually just prefer doing a single operation on a single line (creating the list of random numbers; and sorting that list).

Comment: Yeah same in private but here I'm in a one-liners. rush those days ;). More seriously, using more lines makes it more readable, that is a better way beyond the style to my opinion.